# What is the unit of the difference of two timestamps in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

There are two columns (`t0` and `t1`) whose types are timestamp (`t0 = 2021-11-18 20:25:09` and `t1 = 2021-11-18 20:36:41`)

I want to find `t1 - t0` (expecting ~11 minutes or ~ 700seconds), but the result is 1132.

I was wondering how `-` is done between two timestamps and what the unit is.

Comment: MySQL is quite different from SQLite. I removed the inconsistent tags. Please  add only one database tag.

Comment: @TheImpaler, thanks for the fix.

Comment: So, is it SQLite or MySQL?

Comment: Difference of timestamps is not implemented. Both are converted to numbers by stripping all non numeric characters then the difference of these "numbers" is returned

Answer (score 3):

Use the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function for that purpose

For your question:

mysql converts the string into a number and then subtracts, its deterministic but not the result you want

> ```
> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2021-11-18 20:25:09','2021-11-18 20:36:41')
> ```
>
> ```
> | TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2021-11-18 20:25:09','2021-11-18 20:36:41') |
> | -----------------------------------------------------------------: |
> |                                                                 11 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2021-11-18 20:25:09','2021-11-18 20:36:41')
> ```
>
> ```
> | TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2021-11-18 20:25:09','2021-11-18 20:36:41') |
> | -----------------------------------------------------------------: |
> |                                                                692 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7cd88c2db5cc8c7b7bc62aa1b9912557)*

Comment: Thanks, this works. I still wonder what '-' does, but I will use your solution for now.

Comment: mysql converts the string into a number and the subtracts, its deterministic but not the result you want

Answer (score 0):

```
> SELECT TIMEDIFF(t1, t2) FROM t;
+------------------+
| TIMEDIFF(t1, t2) |
+------------------+
| -00:11:32        |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Please see the example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cff8b78199142a879cb2d767f5b63e8d)

Answer (score 0):

`-` does nothing useful for timestamps, except that the sign of the result will tell you which is greater (assuming month and day are not 0), which is easier tested with a comparison operator.

In general, if you cast a timestamp to a number, you get a number formed by putting the parts of the timestamp together.  For instance:

```
select timestamp('2021-11-18 20:25:09.012345')+0
```

gives

```
20211118202509.012345
```

`-` effectively casts both operands to a number.  So differences in days become differences in millions, differences in months become differences in hundreds of millions, and differences in years become differences in tens of billions.  This doesn't provide any useful measure of the difference between two timestamps.